# How to shut down the computer after a task has been completed?

Tags: command-line, shutdown

I usually start a download before I go to school. 
Which command should I use to automatically make the necessary saves and turn off the computer after a particular task has been completed? 
(Say, after installing the updates, or after downloading a large file.)

I have also cross-posted at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15526/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-after-a-task-has-been-completed).

Answer (score 30):

It depends you started task. If it is some command line tool you could simply run `halt` or `shutdown -h now`:

1. `wget http://..../somelargefile; halt` - `halt` will be executed after `wget`
2. `wget http://..../somelargefile && halt` - `halt` will be executed if `wget` return no errors
3. `wget http://..../somelargefile || halt` - `halt` will be executed if `wget` return errors

Alternative to this is using `kshutdown` - in this app you can specify what action should be done (reboot/shutdown/hibernate/etc or command execution) and when (after some time or when another application exits). If you want to use this tool you need to chose correct process - some update utilities starts few subprocesses.

[image: KShutdown]

Comment: You can also give `shutdown` a time to wait; no need to use kshutdown for that purpose.

Comment: No, but `shutdown` doesn't have any way of waiting for an actual event.

Answer (score 27):

Every process has a directory named according to its process id (pid) in the `proc` filesystem. Therefore you can wait for a specific process' termination by checking whether its directory exists repeatedly.

You can use this to perform a system shutdown after process termination like this (replace 2296 by the pid to wait for):

```
su -c 'while [[ -d /proc/2296 ]]; do sleep 1; done; poweroff'
```

Advantages:

- You can decide whether or not to shutdown after setting off the shell command
- The shutdown is issued as root, the command to wait for is not necessarily done as root (no need to workaround the late `sudo`-password prompt).

Disadvantages:

- It may happen that your process terminates and the OS then reuses the same pid for a newly spawned process within that second (race condition). You'd thus continue to wait for that new process to terminate.

Comment: Main point: This works even if the process has started.

Comment: If you have started something from a terminal that you still have open `ps` in that same terminal should help you spot the PID for the CMD.  If the process was/is in another terminal pipping the ps output for everything through grep to filter for your command should help you find it `ps -elf | grep <command_related_word>`

Comment: Better check my answer based on `pgrep` aka _process grep_...

Comment: How can I put this command into the background?

Comment: @DerWeh Wrap it in a shell script and follow the steps given here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/625409/1025391

Comment: This works on Google Cloud.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to monitor an already started process, you can do this in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
# while pgrep &>/dev/null -f process_name; do sleep 60; done; shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `&&` and `||` operators to chain commands together. For example:

```
apt-get update && sleep 2 && init 0
```

which will perform an update to the system using aptitude, wait 2 seconds, and go to runlevel 0, depending on your system this may or may not actually power off the hardware.

To speak to one or more operations following a more arbitrary operation, such as a, presumably web browser, download you would require additional logic to watch the downloading file to verify that the download has in fact completed, however, the shell logic is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

There is a application, named sentinella which can do it for you with its GUI:
[image: sentinella]

for installing it:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install sentinella
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with download (in Firefox) and backup. I solved it by starting another, parallel bash script. It monitors network traffics. When it is low for some period of time, it will suspend/shutdown the computer.

The heart of the script:

```
ip -s link show  dev wlan0 # This gets transffered bytes on wifi. 
ip -s link show  dev wlan0 | sed -n '4p;6p'         |  awk '{ print $1 }' | paste -sd+ | bc # This combines all the traffic together.
```

So the core function:

```
function statistics { # $1=network $2=seconds
first=$(ip -s link show  dev $1 | sed -n '4p;6p' | awk '{ print $1 }' | paste -sd+ | bc)
sleep $2
second=$(ip -s link show  dev $1 | sed -n '4p;6p' | awk '{ print $1 }'| paste -sd+ | bc)
echo $(( (1 + $second - $first) / $2 )) # simple averadge
return 0
}

while (true); do
 if [ $(statistics wlan0 300) -lt 100000 ]; then 
  sudo pm-suspend # but you must put pm-suspend in "sudo visudo". Say as UserIsMarchingSchool ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
 fi
done
```

Well, a bit crazy, but independent from the original program. May it help you as an hint. I suppose it can be solved in a simpler way. :-)